# Qt5 QUdpSocket does not work on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, qt5, qudpsocket

I can receive QUdp datagram on my Windows Phone but I cannot emit anything, the emitted datagrams are not seen by any of my devices on the network ?
I've set

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
```

in the manifest file.
binding does not report any errors and

```
QHostAddress address;
address.setAddress("127.0.0.1"); //192.168.0.255"); //192.168.0.100"); // 192.168.0.0");
qint64 res = udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), address, portUDP);
bLog->append("Written "+QString::number(res));
```

returns the correct number of bytes written (all errors signals connected to "debug slots" but no one triggered, so no error on 'writeDatagram') but I cannot read/get them on any other device on the network. It is quite frustrating because the *exact same code* runs perfectly on Android, Linux and even on Windows desktop (receive & emit datagrams) - what is blocking the datagrams to exit the Windows Phone ?
Tested with Qt5.3.2, Qt5.4.0 & 5.4.1 - same problem !